# ООП возврат строки

Tags: php, ооп

Имеется класс

```
class Main{
    private $num;

    function num(){
        $value = 40000;
        $this->num = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    function format(){
        return number_format($this->num, 0, '.', ' ');
    }
}
```

Если делаю вызов

```
echo (new Main)->num()->format(); // выведет 40 000
```

Как сделать возврат не отформатированного значения

```
echo (new Main)->num(); // должно вернуть 40000
```

Comment: пардон, добавил возвращение в функции num. Если просто вернуть число, то следующая функция (format) не сработает, не видит ее дальше ->  Call to a member function format() on integer in ...

Comment: `__toString()` перекройте с возвратом `$this->num`

Comment: можно подробнее?

Comment: `function __toString() {
        return (string)$this->num;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

> public __toString ( void ) : string
>
> Метод __toString() позволяет
> классу решать, как он должен реагировать при преобразовании в строку.
> Например, что вывести при выполнении echo $obj;. Этот метод должен
> возвращать строку, иначе произойдёт фатальная ошибка уровня
> E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR.

добавлем в объявление класса

```
function __toString() { return (string)$this->num; }
```

и теперь

```
echo (new Main)->num(); // 40000
```

Но обратите внимание, что эта функция вернет строку, а не число

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/52aecf9e56b52a7a2ad523553e5c2415f568fea3)